# Take a specific word from a file

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP I am trying to perform the following task:

1) read the input file:

```
// some lines
request_context.base_path: /~test1/test2/web/ 
// some lines
```

2) get the following output:

```
/~test1/test2/web/
```

This is my code, but it does not work.
Any ideas? Thanks.

```
<?php
$lines = file('app/parameter.conf');
$l_count = count($lines);
for($x = 0; $x< $l_count; $x++)
{
    if (strpos($lines[$x],'request_context.base_path:') !== false) {
        preg_match('(request_context.base_path:)(\s.*)', $lines[$x], $matches);
        echo $matches[1];
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

why all that fuss?

```
preg_match('/request_context.base_path: (.*)/', $lines[$x], $matches);
```